# Mitsubishi Pajero IO fuel

Tags: fuel-consumption, mitsubishi, pajero

Which is the best fuel to use for Mitsubishi Pajero IO with the below specification:

- MODEL: GF-H66W MRXC
- ENGINE: 4G93

Unleaded 95 ,Unleaded 98 or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a GDI engine model with a compression ratio of 12.0:1 (which is rather high) I'd recommend using the highest-octane fuel available on a regular gas station in your area, which is presumably the Unleaded 98.